# Excel Table: How do I use ONLY the first 30 or 60 rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel and want to do a CountIf on a column, but only the first 30 or 90.  Table is:

```
DATE, Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, Tag4
```

I'm looking to do something like:

> `=COUNTIF(MyTable[Tag4[30]],2)`

I know that is not correct since `MyTable[Tag4[30]]` means nothing and is not a range.  I could do it with `F2:F31`, but since I have to replicate it 4 times (4 Tags), I would rather it be as generic as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OFFSET function to construct the Range

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(MyTable[[#Headers],[Tag4]],1,0,30),2)
```

Comment: Just an FYI for the OP, Offset is volatile.  Volatile means it will recalculate every time Excel Recalculates, even if that recalculation is triggered on another workbook.  Index will only recalculate if the data referred to in the formula changes.  This is not an issue with few uses of OFFSET, but add too many and suddenly the users are complaining about lag for every change made.

Comment: @ScottCraner Oh cool, didn't realise that! I find it marginally clearer though, so I guess that's the trade off

Comment: Yes, there are others, INDIRECT,NOW,TODAY to name a few.  Limiting an learning how to not use them will make Excel quicker and more responsive.  It is akin to using `.Select` or `.Activate` in vba.  It makes things go slower.  There are time that they are needed, but should be avoided if possible.  But that is just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use INDEX():

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(MyTable[Tag4],1):INDEX(MyTable[Tag4],30),2)
```